# In Oreo, I'm not able to get an outgoing number

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get outgoing number but before oreo the code is working absolutely fine but in devices with oreo code is not working.

```
     public class IncomingBroadCastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        Context context;
        WhatsAppContacts requiredContact;
        List<String> messages = new ArrayList<>();
        String callerName="";
        Realm realm;
        String outgoingNumber = "";

        @Override
        public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
            Log.d("Search","onReceive");
            this.context = context;
            realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
            TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                telephony.listen(new PhoneStateListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
                        Log.d("Search","above Ringing"+state);
                        if(state ==  TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){
                            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                            editor.putString("number", incomingNumber);
                            Log.d("Ringing", incomingNumber);
                            editor.apply();
                            Log.d("Search","inside call state changed");
                            initialiseAndStartService();
                        }
                        else if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL")){
                            //Outgoing call
                                String number=intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
                                Log.i("tag","Outgoing number : "+number);
                                if(number!=null){
                                    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                                            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
                                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                                    editor.putString("number", number);
                                    editor.apply();
                                    Log.d("Search","inside call state changed");
                                    initialiseAndStartService();

                                }
                        }
                    }
                },PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

        }

}
```

In versions before oreo it's working completely fine. But in Oreo not able to get outgoing number.

Comment: you should not implement your broadcast listeners using manifest now as of oreo broadcast receivers are implemented in application class of the app. that's why your notifications are not working.

Answer (score 0):

There is a limitation in oreo. You can't register implicit broadcast in manifest and `NEW_OUTGOING_CALL` is an implicit broadcast. You can only get that broadcast work when your app is live and user is interacting with it.
you can find more information [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#broadcasts)

Comment: Then how truecaller is doing this?

Comment: decompile trucaller and see it yourself. That's the best way I used whenever I can't find the solution. search in manifest, services and. broadcasts you will find useful info.

Comment: By analyzing their apk in Android studio I found some useful classes like   `com.truecaller.service.CallStateService`

Answer (score 0):

To get outgoing number i have idea: get it from call history:

```
public static  ArrayList<String> getRecentCall(Context context) {
    ArrayList<String> listRecentCall = new ArrayList<>();

    Uri queryUri = android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI;

    String[] projection = new String[]{
            ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
            CallLog.Calls._ID,
            CallLog.Calls.NUMBER,
            CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME,
            CallLog.Calls.DATE};

    String sortOrder = String.format("%s limit 2 ", CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC");

    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(queryUri, projection, null, null, sortOrder);

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String phoneNumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER));
        listRecentCall.add(phoneNumber);
        //get first number so we only need firt element
        break;
    }
    cursor.close();

    return listRecentCall;
}
```

keep it run in delay 500ms after end call. Hope this can help you

Answer (score 0):

In Oreo, you have to first request for permission to make call.

```
private boolean checkCallPermission() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            String call = Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE;
            String outgoing = Manifest.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS;
            String incoming = Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE;
            int hasCallPermission = checkSelfPermission(call);
            List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<String>();
            if (hasCallPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                permissions.add(call);
                permissions.add(outgoing);
                permissions.add(incoming);
            }
            if (!permissions.isEmpty()) {
                String[] params = permissions.toArray(new String[permissions.size()]);
                requestPermissions(params, REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Then, you have to register a receiver to receive the outgoing call event. You can do that with creation of a class which extends broadcast receiver and declare that receiver in AndroidManifest.xml file. In Android Oreo version you can't declare implicit broadcasts in AndroidManifest.xml file. You have to register the receiver dynamically in Oreo version and above but `NEW_OUTGOING_CALL` has been exempted . So, you can register it statically in AndroidManifest.xml file and it will work in Oreo version as well.

```
public class IncomingAndOutgoingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "OnReceive");
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Log.i(TAG, "action : " + action);
        callHandler(intent);
    }

    private void callHandler(Intent intent) {
        String PhoneNumber = "NA";

        try {
            Log.i(TAG, "State : " + intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE));
            String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            if (state == null) {
                PhoneNumber = "NA";
            } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
                PhoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                Log.d(TAG, "Incoming number : " + PhoneNumber);
            }
            if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL")) {
                PhoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
                Log.d(TAG, "Outgoing number : " + PhoneNumber);
            }
            if (!PhoneNumber.contentEquals("NA")) {
                Log.i(TAG, "PhoneNumber : " + PhoneNumber);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception is : ", e);
        }
    }
}
```

That's it. Complete code is in [here](https://github.com/JayanthAbhi/IncomingAndOutGoingCallApplication)

The project features are as follows:

```
- Make a call.
- Receiver to receive events of 
    * Incoming Calls.
    * Outgoing Calls.
    * Get Outgoing Number.
    * Get Incoming Number.
    * States of the phone(Ex: Idle, Ringing, OffHook).
```